# How to plot degree distribution in C#

Tags: c#, distribution

I wrote some code in C# that generates a random network and I put nodes and links into a WinForms `DataGridView` control.

Now, I want to plot the frequency of degrees of nodes distributed as a chart.
Does anyone know how to do it?

I wrote this code:

```
int f = 0;
        int container = 0;
        while (f < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {

            int count2 = 0;
            container = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[1].Value);

           for (j = f; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value) == container)
                    count2++;
            }

            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[f].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[1].Value;
            dataGridView2.Rows[f].Cells[1].Value = count2;

        f++;
        }
```

but it repeat rows as you see in figure here: [degree distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGCLw.png)

Comment: Why is you degree value always zero?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Don#t you like your data or do you ask how to create a chart? (MSChart control is a good start)..

Comment: Improve formatting a bit